# on the dimension of a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I was reading a book and came across the following: If $f$ is a linear functional on a C*-algebra $A$ such that $a\leq f(a)1$ for all $a\geq 0$, then  $A$ must be finite dimensional.

One possible way to see this is by a way of contradiction. That is, if $A$ is infinite dimensional, the there must exist a linear functional $f$ such that the above inequality does not hold. I could not come up with any such example or could not see any other way to go about it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the logical negation is: If $A$ is infinite dimensional, then to each (continuous?) linear functional $f$ there exists some $a\ge 0$ such that $a  \nleqq  f(a)1$.

Comment: The following may be helpful. For an element $a \ge 0$ such that $\|a\|=1$ the condition $a\le f(a)1$ implies $f(a)\ge 1.$
Assume the algebra contains elements $a_1,\ldots,a_n,$ so that $\|a_k\|=1$ and $a_ka_l=0$ for $k\neq l.$ Then $\|a_1+\ldots +a_n\|=1.$ The condition
$$a_1+\ldots +a_n\le f(a_1+\ldots +a_n)1$$ implies
$$n\le f(a_1)+\ldots +f(a_n)\le f(1)\|f\|\,\|a_1+\ldots+a_n\|=\|f\|^2$$
Therefore $\|f\|^2$ is the maximal possible number of summands. This implies that the spectrum of each positive  element $a$  is finite and $\#\sigma(a)\le \|f\|^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely using far heavier machinery than necessary. But assume to the contrary that we have such an $f$ defined on an infinite-dimensional $A$. Note that $f$ is clearly positive and therefore necessarily bounded. By passing to the double dual, we may assume $A$ is a von Neumann algebra and $f$ is normal. Any infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra admits a separable infinite-dimensional abelian von Neumann subalgebra, so by restricting to such a subalgebra, we may assume $A$ is a separable infinite-dimensional abelian von Neumann algebra and $f$ is normal. But the structure of such an algebra is known and we see that there exists a sequence of nonzero projections $p_n$ converging to $0$ in SOT. But then $f(p_n)1 \to 0$ in norm since $f$ is normal, but $p_n$ all have operator norm $1$, contradicting the assumption that $p_n \leq f(p_n)1$ for all $n$.

Comment: The use of double dual can be avoided by noting that $f$ must be faithful, so if $A$ is infinite-dimensional, then $\pi_f(A)’’$ is an infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra and $f$ extends to a normal linear functional on $\pi_f(A)’’$.